# How to use $routeParams without template (website)

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible use $stateParams without setting $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider?

I would use $stateParams only in few page of my website!

Comment: What do you mean by, "without setting `$stateProvider`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$location.search()` which will give you parameter from URL

If you want to get specific parameter you can do below code

`$location.search().param`

`param` will be parameter name which you want to search.

Comment: so I normally pass like www.mydomain.com/page.html?id=1

Comment: @DigitalXP then you can get `id` by doing like this `$location.search().id`

Comment: Ok working....but after I go to detail page....no other link works! When i pass hover link I see changing in address browser, but when click nothing happen!

Answer (score 1):

For me html5 mode dont work (or I'm not able!). I change in normal mode so.
Put in your config:

```
.config(function($locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
})
```

then make the href link so:

```
<a href="/page_details.html#!/?id=xxx">
```

and then in your controller of details page:

```
var param = $location.search().id;
```

Comment: In order to work `$location.search().id` will always need html5mode & hashPrefix enable. +1 to your answer..